# splice does not delete the current element

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, splice, v-for

I am trying to delete the current item on click, but when i run it it deletes only the last item.
I'm going crazy, on another component I did the same thing and it worked...I don't know why here!
This is the code, I am using various libraries...

```
 <template>
   <div class="hours-container">
     <div class="hours" v-for="(time, index) in hour" :key="index">
       <a-time-picker
         :default-value="moment('08:00', 'HH:mm')"
         format="HH:mm"
         :minute-step="15"
         :allowClear="allowClear"
       />
       <span> to </span>
       <a-time-picker
         :class="time.delete ? '' : 'mr-3'"
         :default-value="moment('00:00', 'HH:mm')"
         format="HH:mm"
         :minute-step="15"
         :allowClear="allowClear"
       />
       <b-icon
         v-if="time.delete"
         icon="x"
         width="20"
         height="20"
         class="delete-time"
         @click="deleteTime(index)"
       ></b-icon>
     </div>
   </div>
 </template>

 <script>
 import moment from "moment";
 export default {
   props: {
     hour: Array,
   },
   data() {
     return {
       allowClear: false, 
     };
   },
   methods: {
     moment, //per impostare l'orario di default
     deleteTime(index) {
       console.log(index);
       //per eliminare uno slot di orari
       this.hour.splice(index, 1);
     },
   },
 };
 </script>
```

ADDITIONAL:

this is the parent component, the part added with emit I highlighted it with EMIT ==>

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 class="options-title mx-auto">What's the options?</h2>
    <b-row class="d-flex ml-2">
      <functional-calendar
        :configs="calendarConfigs"
        @dayClicked="dayClicked"
        ref="Calendar"
      ></functional-calendar>
      <div class="hours-selection-container">
        <div
          class="time-choise d-flex ml-3 mt-2"
          v-for="(day, index) in daySelected"
          :key="index"
        >
          <b-icon
            class="delete-date"
            icon="x-circle"
            variant="danger"
            width="40"
            height="35"
            @click="deleteDate(index, day)"
          ></b-icon>
          <div class="date-times-container d-flex">
            <span class="date-selected">{{ day.selectDay.slice(0, 5) }}</span>
            <Timepicker
              :hour="day.time"
  EMIT==>     v-on:delete-time="onDeleteTime"
            ></Timepicker>
          </div>

          <b-button class="p-0" variant="success" @click="addTime(day)">
            + Add more times
          </b-button>
        </div>
        <div class="user-form-timezone p-4 mx-auto">
          All time displayed in Europe/Rome.
        </div>
      </div>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Timepicker from "./Timepicker.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Timepicker,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
      calendarData: {},
      daySelected: [], //array che conterrà l'oggetto pushato
      calendarConfigs: {
        disabledDates: ["beforeToday"], //disabilita le date precedenti alla data odierna
        //isMultipleDatePicker: true, //abilita la selezione multipla
        datePicker: true, //abilita la selezione singola
        //dateFormat: "dd/mm",
        isMarked: false,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dayClicked(item) {
      //di base viene passato il giorno selezionato e viene convertito in string
      let daySelectedObj = {
        //creo l'oggetto standard che conterrà la data selezionata e un orario di default
        selectDay: item.date,
        time: [
          {
            defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
            defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
          },
        ], //inserisco già uno slot di base per mostrarlo
        other: item, //mi porto dentro anche tutto l'oggetto passato
      };
      //mi prendo il giorno corrente per i controlli
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
      var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); //January is 0!
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      today = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;

      if (!item.isMarked && item.date >= today) {
        //se il giorno passato non ha la proprietà isMarked e se è superiore o uguale ad oggi
        this.daySelected.push(daySelectedObj); //inserisco dentro l'array l'oggetto creato
        item.isMarked = true; //imposto la proprietà marked true per evidenziare sul calendario il giorno cliccato
      }
    },
 EMIT==>     onDeleteTime(index) {
      console.log(index);
      this.hour.splice(index, 1);
    },
    addTime(array) {
      //aggiungo uno o più slot di orario all'interno del giorno selezionato
      //creo l'oggetto standard con l'orario di default
      const defaultHour = {
        defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
        defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
        delete: true, //mi serve per abilitare l'icona x solo sugli orari aggiunti e non sul primo
      };
      array.time.push(defaultHour); //inserisco all'interno dell'array time (che è all'interno dell'array daySelected) lo slot dell'orario scelto
      //console.log("ARRAY", array);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use the index as key if you plan to remove certain items. Use (or introduce) a unique ID that does not change when items are removed.

Answer (score 1):

`splice` mutates the array which tries to mutate the prop, but in vue we cannot change props from child component, so you should emit an event to the parent component with the `index` as payload :

```
deleteTime(index) {
       console.log(index);
       this.$emit("delete-time",index)
     },
```

in parent :

```
   <child @delete-time="onDeleteTime" .../>

...

methods:{
 onDeleteTime(index) {
      
       this.hour.splice(index, 1);
     },
}
```

Comment: `deleteTime(index) {
       console.log(index);
       this.$emit("delete-time",index)
     },`
does this go into the child component?

Comment: Yes, it should be in child component

Comment: gives me this error: 
v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined"

Comment: please share the parent component code i want to know the value of prop `hour` how it's passed in parent to child

Comment: replace `this.hour.splice(index, 1);` by `this.day.time.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: in console says this error: 

`on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined"`

Comment: i think it should be `this.daySelected.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: dayselected is the array which contains the elements containing .time... I cycled it into the component, day matches the single element inside daySelected... so this.daySelected.splice (index, 1) would delete everything.