# splice don't cancelled a right row vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, delete-file, splice

i have an array of objects that i pass myself from another class.
I would like to remove depending on where I click

here I pass the object which is an array

```
  <Timepicker :hour="day.time"></Timepicker>
```

here I cycle the object

```
   <div class="hours" v-for="(time, index) in hour" :key="index">
```

here I recall the function by clicking on an icon

```
  <b-icon
    v-if="time.delete"
    icon="x"
    width="20"
    height="20"
    class="delete-time"
    @click="deleteTime(hour, index)"
  ></b-icon>
```

here I pass it through the props

```
  props: {
    hour: Object(),
  }
```

and here I do the delete function

```
deleteTime(hour, index) {
  this.hour.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Is this the same as your previous question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927581/splice-not-working-with-a-array-row-vue-js

Comment: This question (as well as the duplicate) also seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910791/splice-does-not-delete-the-current-element (written by a different user, who might be the same person as this user).